# can I break line in the middle of variable list, in a do file in Stata

Tags: stata

I am writing a Stata do file, I am doing a regression (actually `gologit2`, but I don't think this detail is important) with a long list of IV's. It would really help the clarity of the script if I could break the lines in the middle of the IV list. I tried using `\\\` but with no success ( found this suggestion on another forum), this just yields

> '/' not allowed in varlist'/'

error message.

I tried looking for the solution in Stata help, but with no success.

Answer (score 3):

That is because `\\\` does not break a line in Stata.

To break a line you can use `///`. Alternatively you can end a line with `/*` and begin the next one with `*/`

Comment: thanks a million! I used the '/* */' solution,  and it works now!